# Can I safely update react and react-dom without updating react-scripts?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have used CRA on a project for 2 years now.

Currently, my packages are on the following outdated versions but I want to update to React 16.8 because it's a peer-dependency for a lot of npm packges I want to use.

```
"react": "^16.8.0",

"react-dom": "^16.8.0",

"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

"react-scripts": "1.1.0",
```

Can I safely update react and react-dom to 16.8 without updating react-scripts?

Note, I tried updating CRA (react-scripts) to 2.x.x recently and it caused a bunch of my older libraries to fail.

Comment: What version of React are you currently using?  Whenever updating dependencies I would recommend reading through release notes and checking to see if your project has any breaking changes.

CRA 2.x.x uses newer versions of webpack which doesn't play nicely with older dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend, unless there is a need on it. (Like a security breach)

You probably will find some compatibility issues, and for this to work, you will need to update your dependencies.

Comment: I'm trying to use `material-ui` and unfortunately, it requires 16.8 in all the recent versions.